# CONCAT_WS in SQL Server with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements, concat-ws

I want to create a **View** in **SQL Server**, there is new column in View name **TotalApproval**, that column concat string value of some columns in record with condition like code below, but the syntax is not right, please solve for me

```
CREATE VIEW WorkflowRequestViews AS
SELECT ApplicationNo, DescriptionNo, BelongSite as Site, 
        cast(FaxCode as nvarchar(50)) as FaxCode, 
        cast(MainApproval as nvarchar(100)) as MainApproval, 
        TotalStep, Process, UrgencyLevel, Complete, 
        CAST(CONCAT_WS(',', SectionMGR, DepartmentMGR, FactoryManager,
        CASE 
            WHEN BelongSite = 'FVB' THEN Director,ACCMGR 
            ELSE ACCPIC2
        END) as nvarchar(255)) as TotalApproval
FROM BusinessTrips
```

I want  column TotalApproval is a string contain value which join from column I selected seperate by ',' with condition

**SOLVE**: Just concat value in **THEN** clause like code below:

```
CREATE VIEW WorkflowRequestViews AS
SELECT ApplicationNo, DescriptionNo, BelongSite as Site, 
        cast(FaxCode as nvarchar(50)) as FaxCode, 
        cast(MainApproval as nvarchar(100)) as MainApproval, 
        TotalStep, Process, UrgencyLevel, Complete, 
        CAST(CONCAT_WS(',', SectionMGR, DepartmentMGR, FactoryManager,
        CASE 
            WHEN BelongSite = 'FVB' THEN CONCAT_WS(',',Director,ACCMGR) 
            ELSE ACCPIC2
        END) as nvarchar(255)) as TotalApproval
FROM BusinessTrips
```

Comment: `THEN Director,ACCMGR  ELSE ACCPIC2` won't work. Each branch needs to return a single value. So you will need to concatenate those two columns (`Director,ACCMGR`) and return the concatenated result as a single value for that branch

Comment: Don't put the solution in the question. You are free to answer your own question below.

Answer (score 1):

You could use two `CASE` expressions, as `CONCAT_WS` ignores nulls

```sql
CAST(
  CONCAT_WS(',',
    SectionMGR,
    DepartmentMGR,
    FactoryManager,
    CASE WHEN BelongSite = 'FVB' THEN Director END,
    CASE WHEN BelongSite = 'FVB' THEN ACCMGR ELSE ACCPIC2 END
  )
  as nvarchar(255)
)
```